# How to toggle a specific class on an element where there are multiple classes assigned?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I have an element that has multiple classes. I would like to just switch between one of the classes when I click it.

```
<span class="icon-expand desktop-only mt8 pl4" id="toggle-site-content-width"></span>
```

When I click this, I need to just change `icon-expand` into `icon-reduce`, and just leave the other classes as is.

It just adds the class at the end when I'm using `$(this).toggleClass('icon-reduce')`. Same happens when I'm doing this: `$(this).toggleClass('icon-expand','icon-reduce')`.

This is the full code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#toggle-site-content-width').click(function(){  //  on click
        $('#site-content').children('div').toggleClass('content-align-center');  //  remove this class to expand the view to full available window width
        $(this).toggleClass('toggle-expand','icon-reduce');  //  change the icon
        $(this).trigger('resize');  //  trigger the window to rearrange masonry bricks
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change:

```
$(this).toggleClass('toggle-expand','icon-reduce');
```

to:

```
$(this).toggleClass('toggle-expand icon-reduce');
```

You don't need to separate your classes by `,` here.

Comment: What the first one will do actually.? or is that a syntax error.?

Comment: Yes it's wrong way for toggling between two classes.